# Why can a Nim sum be written as powers of 2?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I have this confusion. Why do we express a nim sum as powers of 2 and why do nim sums cancel in pairs of 2 only?

For instance, let's take the nim game(6,10,15) 
Now clearly
*6 = * $2^2$ + * $2^1$
*10 = * $2^3$ + * $2^1$
*15 = * $2^3$ + * $2^2$ + * $2^1$ + * $2^0$

Then the nim sum will be given by *6 + *10 + *15 = *3 but why is it that only powers of 2 cancel in pairs? Any player can remove one single nim from the first heap of 6 or may be even 5 but it looks as if the player is going to remove only 4 ( $2^2$) or 2 ($2^1$) nims only? Why is that so?

And also we don't we write *6 as sum of 5 and 1 or 3 and 3.. Now if express all 3 in this way and add any three pairs then the sum is no longer *3

Comment: The answer is rather long. I suggest that you try reading [this brief treatment](http://www.mif.pg.gda.pl/nkm/files/nim.pdf), [this somewhat longer one](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-games4), and the very thorough treatment in [this PDF](http://www.mif.pg.gda.pl/nkm/files/nim.pdf) first; if they don’t fully answer your question, they should at least help you to pin down exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I see that the authors of the mentioned articles uses binary number approach for granted.Now with this method again we try and reach out for 0 and 1 pairs. However these 0s and 1s are coefficients of a number expressed as powers of 2 which again means we remove everything in powers of 2. Seems like I am still missing what you were trying to hint.

Comment: I think that you’re probably looking for something that isn’t there: we use powers of $2$ because that’s how the theory works out. It’s not a matter of taking them for granted: they’re implicit in the game, waiting to be discovered by anyone who looks hard enough.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Your first and third links are identical. http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~ejf/pfiles/nimgroups.pdf is another PDF about this question (or at least a very related one).

Comment: Loved the paper @MarkS.Thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brian said, a rigorous proof that this powers-of-two strategy works would be quite long. I'll try to provide a bit of intuition, though with a piece of a proof.

---

When you have a game of nim with two equal piles, the next player to move won't win (if the opponent plays well) because the other player could always mirror moves. Now, we can say a bunch of piles is *like* a single pile when the next player would lose if you added the single pile to the bunch. For example, (1,5) is like 4 since the second player can win (1,5,4).

The key fact then is that $(m,2^n)$ is like $m+2^n$ if $2^n>m$. You can prove that the second player can win $(m,2^n,m+2^n)$ by induction. It's clear for m=0, certainly.

Otherwise, the first move might be in the biggest pile, leaving it at least as large as $2^n$, and then the second player can make the smallest pile equal to the difference or the other two, and they then have a winning strategy by inductive hypothesis (m is now lower).

In the other case, if the first move leaves only one pile that's at least as big as $2^n$, then you can always move in that pile to the binary xor (the binary sum without carrying) of the other two piles. By using the inductive hypothesis repeatedly (lower values of n), you can pull out and cancel the highest powers of two that appear to see that the second player has a mirroring-like strategy.

---

But why wouldn't something like this work for, say, $3^n$? Basically because numbers aren't sums of distinct powers of 3, if the leading term of a base three expansion is $2*3^n$, then since two piles that are the same power of three would cancel, we can't hope to get as clean a decomposition that way.

What about something with no 2s, like the fibonacci base? Then either representations aren't unique or aren't fully arbitrary, so you can't move to an arbitrary xor.

Comment: It's not really clear why powers of $3$ wouldn't work. Could you please elaborate on that a bit? Yes, I get that numbers aren't sums of distinct powers of $3$, but I don't understand your next sentence. What do you mean by we can't get a clean decomposition?

Comment: @S.D. Suppose $3^n>m$, and then consider the number $2*3^n+m$. We shouldn't get a result like "the second player can win $(m,3^n,3^n,m+2*3^n)$" since the two piles of size $3^n$ would cancel. So it's not as simple as decomposing $m+2*3^n$ into sums of powers of $3$. This raises a new question of "why not sums of powers of $3$ and twice powers of $3$?" Well, at the very least nothing like the "key fact" works any more: If you have (in base 3) $(200,11,211)$, then you can move in $211$ to $121$, and there's no move in $(200,11,121)$ that makes it look like $(100,11,111)$ or $(100,21,121)$, etc.